# Native stack navigator working in Expo Go, but it is showing a blank screen on Apple Testflight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

I have created a bare minimum example of the issue below. When I build this in Expo Go, I am able to see the screen that states `Navigation working...` but once I build the application in expo dev and submit it to Apple Testflight, I can only see a blank screen.

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'; // required dependency for native-stack
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const MapScreen = () => {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Navigation working...</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="stackScreen"
          component={MapScreen}
          initialParams={{ link: data }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I was originally using `createStackNavigator` but have realised I should be using `createNativeStackNavigator`.

Comment: Ensure that all your dependencies, including @react-navigation/native and @react-navigation/native-stack, are up-to-date and compatible with each other. Sometimes, version mismatches can cause unexpected behavior.